# How can I get my Java program to output correctly using a final double and multiple discounts?

Tags: java

I am writing a Java program and I want to use a switch, but there is a set price or final double and multiple discounts. This is frustrating and I don't want to have to cast Int's either.

For full disclosure - I am a 37 yr old student, so any help would be great. Here is what I have. On a side note using if else if statements was easy, but this is a different animal with so many variable discounts. The code prints the total, but ignores all of the cases and falls through to default.

```
package example;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class AcmeShirtsSwitch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        final double SHIRT_COUNT = 19.95;

        double shirt = SHIRT_COUNT;

        // Get number of shirts purchased.
        System.out.println("Enter the number of shirts "
                + "you have purchased to see your discount. ");

        int shirts = input.nextInt();


        int discount = (int)(shirts * shirt);
        switch (discount) {

        case 1:
            discount = (int) .40;
            break;
        case 2:
            discount = (int) .30;
            break;
        case 3:
            discount = (int) .20;
            break;
        case 4:
            discount = (int) .10;

        default:
            discount = 0;
            break;
        }
        double finalDiscount = (shirt * shirts) * (1.0 - discount);

        System.out.println("Your discount is " + discount);
        System.out.println("Your total is " + finalDiscount);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't `switch` on a `double`, it's not allowed by the language syntax and would be hard to do correctly anyways. Just use an `if-else` block instead of a `switch`. Also, keep in mind that your assignment `discount = (int) .40` is not doing what you expect it to do. Test it in a simple program by printing the output the console and you will see that it behaves oddly.

Comment: When you cast a floating point number to an int in Java, it truncates the fraction -- just drops it. So, `(int) 0.40` is equal to 0, and so are the others. You should have a separate variable to hold those 0.40, 0.30, etcs, and have that be a `double`.

Comment: I'd start by renaming SHIRT_COUNT to SHIRT_PRICE. Doubles are bad for prices, look around. Use a DECIMAL. and make everything DECIMAL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I figured out to my problem. It is not perfect i.e decimal places, but it works.

package example;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class AcmeShirtsSwitch {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    final double SHIRT_PRICE = 19.95;

    double shirt = SHIRT_PRICE;

    // Get number of shirts purchased.
    System.out.println("Enter the number of shirts "
            + "you have purchased to see your discount. ");

    int shirts = input.nextInt();

    double discount;
    switch (shirts) {

    case 1:
        discount = 0.0;
        break;
    case 2:
        discount = 0.0;
        break;
    case 3:
        discount = .10;
        break;
    case 4:
        discount = .10;
        break;
    case 5:
        discount = .20;
        break;
    case 6:
        discount = .20;
        break;
    case 7:
        discount = .20;
        break;
    case 8:
        discount = .30;
        break;
    case 9:
        discount = .30;
        break;
    case 10:
        discount = .30;
        break;
    case 11:
        discount = .30;
        break;
    case 12:
        discount = .40;
        break;
    default:
        discount = .40;
        break;

    }
    double finalDiscount = (shirt * shirts) * (1.0 - discount);

    System.out.println("Your discount is " + discount);
    System.out.println("Your total is " + finalDiscount);

    System.exit(1);

}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

This code has several issues:

- variable names: try to find variable names that are telling a bit more about their purpose. helps a lot to understand the code.
- `(int) (shirt * shirts)` will always be either 0 or atleast 19, so the `switch(discount)` doesn't make a lot of sense.
- this kind of cast `(int) .40`, same for `.30` and all other doubles in the switch will always result in 0.
- assigning `SHIRT_COUNT`, (which should be the price, i guess, see 1. point) to `shirt` is senseless, since `shirt` is never overwritten. Simply use `SHIRT_COUNT` directly instead.
- the discount in the `switch` follows one simple rule:

  ```
  if(discount < 4)
      discount = .50 - 0.1 * discount;
  else
      discount = 0;
  ```

Just to cover the most important issues.

Comment: I agree it seems pointless and I have a program using if, else if statements, but I must do this in a switch. Thanks for your knowledge thus far.

Answer (score 1):

Since `shirt` is 19.95, multiplying it by any integer will never result in 1, 2, 3 or 4. Instead of using the `discount` variable, try switching on `shirts`: this already contains the amount of shirts you're going to buy and can actually be in [1, 4] range.

```
double discount;
    switch (shirts) {

    case 1:
        discount = .40;
        break;
    case 2:
        discount = .30;
        break;
    case 3:
        discount = .20;
        break;
    case 4:
        discount = .10;

    default:
        discount = 0;
        break;
    }
```

Doubles are not exact enough for prices, check out `BigDecimal` instead.

(Also, it doesn't make much sense to give the biggest discount for the lowest possible amount of shirts, does it?)

Comment: Maybe they're trying to discourage people from buying shirts. ;)

Comment: @DavidConrad - or encouraging to buy them one by one.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I tried doing it the way you suggested, but it still falls through, however I was able to remove all of the casting Int's.

Comment: @tattooedtech - try debugging through your code, see how the variables are assigned and changed. Most modern IDEs provide such functionality.

Comment: This is what I get. ERROR: JDWP Unable to get JNI 1.2 environment, jvm->GetEnv() return code = -2
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_NO_JNI_ENV(183):  [util.c:840]

Comment: Seems like a problem with your IDE rather than the program itself. Try adding debug logs instead - print something after every operation, analyze how the program works. (Although you might want to correctly set up your environment eventually.)

Comment: @tattooedtech that's a server-error. Probably the IDE you're using, or the server you use to test the code. Run it on a local JVM instead.

Comment: @DavidConrad, I have posted the answer to my issue. Could you look it over and let me know what you think. It works. Thank you.